# Cannot resolve symbol 'action_settings'

Tags: android, android-fragments

The following is the code fragment of my android program, I'm facing two errors. One is at the `R.menu.menu_main` where it's showing an error on main as `Cannot Resolve Symbol "menu"` and the other one is on `R.id.action_settings`where it also shows that `action_settings Cannot Resolve the Symbol`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is the activity_main XML File

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: Before people start suggesting how to solve "cannot resolve problems", can you post your menu_main.xml? And tell us which folder it is being stored at?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the fact that (probably!) you don't have any menu file declared with the properties you are trying to access to, therefore when R class is built, it can't just see them.

In order to solve this, just try the following steps:

1. Create a *directory* inside `/app/res` named `menu` (right click on
   `res` directory, than choose `new directory` in the context menu and
   name it `menu`)
2. Create a new *xml file* in the `menu` directory just
   created and name it `menu_game` (right click on `menu` directory,
   choose XML in the context menu, then Layout XML File and name it
   `menu_game`)
3. Open the `menu_game.xml` created and cut/paste the following code:

   ```
   <item
   android:id="@+id/action_settings"
   android:orderInCategory="100"
   android:title="my menu Item!"
   app:showAsAction="never"/>
   ```
4. (Optional) if app is not recognized properly (last line is red...) try to fix it by pressing alt-enter shortcut (with the cursor on the exact line). This should declare a namespace for app (a schema to retrieve it). Your final `menu_game.xml` file should look something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item
       android:id="@+id/action_settings"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       app:showAsAction="never"/>
   </menu>
   ```
5. (Optional) Clean and build the project again, now everything should work.

I tried it myself and it worked on my platform. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's different in Fragment

```
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }



  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

and also don't forget to add in OnCreate of Fragment

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }
```

Sample of menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_check"
            android:title="@string/done"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: @RajuIn Are you doing this in Fragment ?

Comment: @RajuIn Also are you sure you create menu in path like this res/menu/menu_main ?

Comment: It was not menu_main but was activity_main but still the issue is not solved.

Comment: @RajuInSo you still not see R.menu.activity_main ?? That's mean that it's not there. Create new one just tap on folder menu and create new one. Also could you share activity_main code

Comment: I'd updated the question with the starting of activity_main XML File please do check it and have a word on it...

Comment: @RajuIn this is a layout, not the menu. I update my answer to show style of menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

create a new directory named menu and then open an xml editor for the same and then copy paste the code in the new xml file of the menu directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="my menu Item!"
            android:showAsAction="always"/>
    </menu>
```

This made me resolve the error. Hope it does for you as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try cleaning the project by clicking Build > Clean for the menu bar in Android Studio.